# iOS iTunes Album Cover type (or similar) Image Display

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Is there any tutorials that show how to make a Image display similar to the Album Art diaply in iTunes? Or anything similar. I followed code posted [here](https://github.com/alexrepty/Paging-Enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews), but I just cannot seem to get it working in the new XCode. Opening his project works fine, but using it in my own, the UIImageView renders the images beyond it's borders, making them appear over each other.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you're talking about CoverFlow?

I wrote a free, very easy to use CoverFlow library. It's modelled on the way that UITableView works, so if you can use that, you can use this. You can get it from here:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Looks great, will definitely have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Man I wish I could upvote this multiple times. This is perfect, awesome work!